How to achieve Hi-Lo Normalmap bakes with the new RayPortal BSDF
Cartesian Caramel shows that you can F12 'renderbake' textures by using a bit of geometry nodes and the new RayPortal BSDF.
Its magnitudes faster than the traditional Bake Operator and also provides more freedom to the artist.
He presents baking normals from procedural materials,
but I want to achieve high to lowpoly normal baking, which seems possible in theory but needs to overcome some hurdles. mostly in getting the correct Tangents, BiTangents and then calculating the correct tangent space.
A playground file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sYC8eF7WBHPehMxIihTobjyNa_NdD072/view?usp=sharing
The geometry node setup on your lowpoly is:
• Storing vertex positions for a simple RayCast Cage
• Storing normals, Bitangents, tangents...
The material in your lowpoly is:
• Rayportal BSDF using 'RayCast Cage' for position, inverted normal for direction.
• some AOVs for calculation in the compositor
The material setup on your highpoly is:
• some AOVs for calculation in the compositor
I tried to leave it as simple as possible, but a few deadends are still in there to play around with.
Just hit F12, then it should render all necessary AOVs from lowpoly and highpoly and send it to the compositor.
In the compositor I try to calculate a Mikk Tangent space normal map.
Its not correct.
In the Upper left is the incorrect 'renderbake'.
Next to it on the right is a correct Suzanne hi-lo tangent normal bake from the traditional Bake Operator. For comparison.
Cheat sheet to get your head around the file:

Lets try to get as close as possible! Thanks in advance to anyone fiddling around with this.
Thanks to Cartesian Caramel for his Tangent GeoNode!

The new WHAT?

@TheLabCat The new Ray Portal BSDF which was implemented in 4.2 Alpha. But usually questions about alpha and beta releases ate off-topic here, rbx 775. Only questions about stable releases are "allowed" here, because generally alpha and beta releases often have bugs and are still subject to lots of changes before the official stable release, which might lead to questions about issues which are probably not existent anymore upon release or might result in answers that become disfunctional or obsolete in stable versions. Apart from that not everyone uses them so knowledge is limited.

Understandable, however I hope this will be treated as an exception since its not about the RayPortal BSDF node itself but about constructing Tangent Space normals from a pseudo Bumpmap. It just utilizes the RayPortal BSDF.

Hi, @GordonBrinkmann I hope this is an exception too, since the question is substantially about the maths and the plumbing, which will persist. and it's well-prepared, described and illustrated.

rbx: Still, you may have to trim your expectations, not everyone will have the alpha installed, and won't necessarily feel they're letting anyone down by not answering until release. If you do find a limited response, there are some  specific technical elements you could strip out of this question, and ask each on their own. That approach may fit SE format better, attract better answers, and be more useful/searchable in the archive. 'Too broad' may be a valid objection.. we'll see how folks feel.

@rbx775 It's maybe not about the Ray Portal BSDF itself, but the title suggests that knowledge about it is helpful/necessary, which might be the first obstacle for attracting users to deal with the problem and therefore get less users even reading the question in the first place. As Robin said, maybe you can strip those parts out of the question which are about the technical/mathematical side of the problem and find answers to that.

There is now a baking example on the original pull request that contains a setup for baking tangent space normal maps.
Looking at your setup one thing I noticed was that the edges are only split after the tangent calculation. I believe they need to be split along UV seams beforehand (but keeping the original vertex normals stored, so they can be used in the tangent calculation).
Another thing that will introduce differences to the usual mikktspace calculations is the choice of triangulation. (I think the tangent calculation for quads is off, so just picking a triangulation like shortest diagonal for the bake geometry might be easiest)
This might not fully answer your question, but should give you additional things to look at.

First off: Thanks for your RayPortal BSDF Patch, it is very much appreciated! :)
Im sure this will make baking alot more convenient!
Just a few hours ago I also fixed my setup and was getting tangent space normalmaps out of the compositor successfully! Your setup looks much cleaner  than mine.
But one thing I did was normalizing the 'RayTrace Cages' distance, because I fiddled around with the Bump to normal node in the highpoly material earlier.
I will compile a definitive file and post it here aswell. Thanks for all your work for the Blender community <3. What a guy
